# MVC Razor View rendering issue

Tags: html, model-view-controller, view, rendering

Afternoon SO.

I am currently scratching my head over an issue regarding the passing of parameters into my MVC view.

**Scenario:**
I have the Razor/HTML view. It contains an img control. When I navigate to the page, without a parameter, the image renders... when I navigate and include a further '/parameter' - it does not render.
***I must be doing something incredibly stupid - but what?***

**View**

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Tender";
}

@using JobList.Models.Pages
@model TenderPage

    <h3 style="margin-top:5px;">New Tender</h3>
    <p style="margin-top:-12px;"><b>Required fields are marked with an asterix (*)</b></p>
    <div style="float:left; margin:-10px 8px 8px 0px; height:30px;">
        <img id="unlockImg" src="../Content/Images/Shared/lock32.png" alt="Unlock" title="Unlock" style="visibility:collapse; position:absolute;" />
        <img id="saveImg" src="../Content/Images/Shared/disk32.png" alt="Update" title="Update" style="visibility:visible; position:absolute;" />
    </div>
```

**Controller (Simplified):**

```html
public ActionResult Tender(Int32? ID = null)
{
  return View(GenerateTender(ID));
}

private TenderPage GenerateTender(Int32? ID)
{
  TenderPage page = new TenderPage();

  using (EnquiriesWorkUnit workUnit = EnquiriesWorkUnit.Begin())
  {
    page.Tender = new Tender();

    if (ID.HasValue && ID.Value > 0)
    {
      //SOMETHING
    }
  }

return page;
}
```

[image: Without Parameter]

[image: With Parameter]

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I am being a numpty.
Adding the parameter the way I was is altering the relative-path for the image source.

Fixed by removing the '..' (relative pathing) on the source-path.